# Webview layout on Samsung Galaxy Note (GT-N7000)

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

Here is my webview (without content) on Galaxy Note: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YebnZ.png

I can't find how I can use all spaces.

I tried to create layout folders with resolution name (hdpi, ...) but it's not working :(

Here is the code of my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webview_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"   
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me to take all space on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an appropriate `<supports-screens>` element to your manifest to indicate that you support large-screen devices:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: Eclipse tell me that :
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 'android'
(same for normalScreens and smalScreens) :(

Comment: @Romain: Set your build target to Android 1.6 or higher. In Eclipse this is in Project > Properties > Android.